# Next/Link refreshes page on shallow routing

Tags: routes, next.js, next-link

I have a `Link`:

```
<Link href={href} passHref shallow>
      <StyledLink
        $active={active}
        $disabled={disabled}
        onClick={() => passBackNumber(number)}
      >
        {number}
      </StyledLink>
</Link>
```

where `StyledLink` is my `styled.a` element and `onClick` passes number that was just clicked. I found information that if you want to use `<Link/>` + `styled-components` you need to use `passHref`. But issue is even though I specified `shallow`, page still is getting refreshed. I only want to url to change and trigger callback. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handle this type of implementation is to use the [Extended Styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) feature of styled-components. I make a styled-component that is tied to Next's `<Link>`:

```js
const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  a, a:focus, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
`
```

In the render function, I will apply the `onClick` event directly into the nested `<a>` tag like this:

```js
<StyledLink href="#">
  <a onClick={ () => passBackNumber(number) }>
</StyledLink>
```

Depending on what version of Next you're using, you may not need `passHref` or `shallow` anymore. Next 12.1+ with Webpack 5+ can now leverage Rust-native compiling server-side with `swc` & styled-components ([more here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler)).

Comment: I tried it, but page keeps refreshing. I'm using Next v10.2.3

Comment: Figured it out, my link needed to start from one of the pages in my app.